# How do I make a "landmine"?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to hurt my victims where if they head to a certain X and Z, they get blown up, and it should be quicker than TNT.

How do I make a landmine with this concept?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using just regular TNT or creepers, OR even just commands, use this:

1. Find flat land
2. Dig a 3x2x2 hole (3x, 2y, 2z, z and x can be swapped)
3. View from above:

|P|O|R|

|T|R|R|

- P = pufferfish
- T = tnt minecart on top of activator rails
- R = redstone
- O = observer face pointing left

4. Cover up! (Note: the blank space between the por and trr is not supposed to be there. Idk how to fix it.)

Answer (score 2):

You will need a certain point that once someone heads to the location, an invisible creeper gets summoned. For this, you need 2 Always Active Repeating Command Blocks.

#1: Creeper Invisibility

```
effect @e[type=creeper] ~ ~ ~ invisibility 2 1 true
```

#2: Act of Explosion

```
execute @a[x=#,z=#,dx=0,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ summon creeper
```

This will leave in a few invisible creepers if any survived. Make a redstone clock that should take a while before removing all creepers in the area.

The commands to be used:

#3: Creeper Extinction (Impulse Needs Redstone)

```
kill @e[type=creeper,x=#,z=#,dx=#,dz=#]
```

#4: Gunpowder Removal (To Destroy Any Remains of Creepers) (Impulse Needs Redstone / Always Active Conditional Chain)

```
kill @e[type=item,name=Gunpowder]
```

**Notes:**

- All `#` should be replaced with the numbers depending on the coordinates and distance of the explosion.